# Can the PWA app name be removed from the title bar?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

It seems that PWA apps, when installed, always display the app name (or short_name, I'm not sure) in the window title bar.

So the app title bar always has a prefix: `{app name} - {html document title}`

Is it possible to remove the app name from the title bar? Or is there another way at runtime to be able to override the complete text in the title bar?

(This behavior is present with Edge or Chrome on Windows, haven't tested other platforms)

Comment: There is also a proposal for a 'Borderless' display mode (https://github.com/WICG/manifest-incubations/blob/gh-pages/borderless-explainer.md) without any browser-mandated window frame, but it's currently only targeting Isolated Web Apps [2], which are still in development. [2]: https://github.com/WICG/isolated-web-apps

Answer (score 2):

A possible (albeit hacky) solution is the [Window Controls Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window_Controls_Overlay_API) display mode. [web.dev has a great tutorial](https://web.dev/window-controls-overlay)

Set the `display_override` property of your manifest to `["window_controls_overlay"]`

You can then use the `titlebar-area-x`, `titlebar-area-y`, `titlebar-area-width`, `titlebar-area-height` CSS environment variables to position a custom title bar where the default one would be.

The only issue is that the user has to manually opt in to this by clicking the "Hide title bar" button:
[image: Image of the default title bar in a Chrome PWA with the Hide title bar button selected]